# Combined flair seems to be broken

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, flair, combined-flair

It appears that my flair icon returns a error:

https://stackexchange.com/users/flair/5680848.png

And the page:
https://stackexchange.com/users/5680848/damian-nikodem?tab=flair

Does not show the example of said flair.

Am I the only one ?